# Get merged account IDs

Tags: salesforce

I am about to do the process of mass de-duping in Salesforce. However, our team uses excel spread sheets where they have Account IDs. When I will merge accounts, then some of them won't exist in Salesforce anymore. I would like to get merged Account IDs to use vlookup in Excel, to replace invalid values.

I tried to pull this data out via Account History report... I wasn't able to do this. Also I went to Recycle Bin, where deleted Accounts are stored. However, there I can find only Account names instead of Account IDs

Does anyone know how can I get the merged Account IDs?

Answer (score 2):

You could use some screenscraping thingie to inspect the HTML of Recycle Bin page. The Id of deleted record is hidden in the checkbox you click.

```
<input id="ids0" name="ids" onclick="..."
title="Select Sample Account" type="checkbox" value="001xxxxxxxxxxxx">
```

But that's a very crappy solution.

---

Better would be to use an API tool (I usually recommend Real Force Explorer but if it's an one-time action the web-based workbench.developerforce.com might do too).

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_merge.htm

> To find all records that have been merged since a given point in time,
>   you can use queryAll() with a SELECT statement similar to the
>   following:
>
> SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE isDeleted=true and masterRecordId != null
>   AND SystemModstamp > 2006-01-01T23:01:01+01:00

In your case something like this should give you both old and new Id - perfect for mapping in Excel!

```
SELECT Id, Name, MasterRecordId, MasterRecord.Name 
FROM Account
WHERE isDeleted=true and MasterRecordId != null
```

[image: Workbench]

Answer (score 0):

Use a soql query tool or apex with soql query. The old accounts should be there and marked with IsDeleted true
I work on Mac and use SOQLExplorer 
You can also use th SF Workbench. Log onto SF and under your name look for it